# 'User' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get all tweets from specific user, but while I am iterating threw tweets in template I get `'User' object is not iterable`

Views

```
tweets = User.objects.get(username__iexact='username')
return render_to_response('timeline.html', {'tweets': tweets})
```

Template

```
{% for tweet in tweets %}
    <h3>{{tweet.text}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

What is other option to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you getting a User if you want to iterate through tweets?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `.get()` gives you an object, and not queryset, so you cannot iterate. Second, The user object, does not generally have a `text` attribute. Do you have a tweet model and how does it look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a User object to your template as tweets. You probably need something like this:

```
user = User.objects.get(username__iexact='username')
return render_to_response('timeline.html', {'tweets': user.tweets})
```

Comment: Or possibly `user.tweet_set.all()`, depending on how the model is set up.